# Why isn't my choice of element fixed by the automorphism of this subgroup of $Gal(\Bbb Q(w_{20})/Q)$?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Given the twentieth root of unity a splitting for it's minimal polynomial is clearly $\Bbb Q(w_{20})$ where $w_{20}$ is the twentieth primitive root of unity. As the isomorphisms only map to roots of the minimal polynomial it only maps to primitive roots and so the Galois group is $G\cong \Bbb U_{20}$ I have a question about one of the Galois correspondences between the subfields of $\Bbb Q(w_{20})$ and the subgroups of $G$ in particular though . Consider the subgroup $\langle 9 \rangle$.

It seems to me that the element $w+w^9$ would be fixed by this group as (denoting $\sigma$ the automorphism which generates this group ) $\sigma(w+w^9)=w^9+w^{81}=w^9+w^1$. However in my course notes it says that the element fixed by this subgroup is $w^2+w^{18}$. I can see from applying the automorphism that this is indeed fixed but I don't understand why my choice of element wasn't valid .. Could anyone please explain this to me ?

Comment: There are infinitely many elements fixed by $\sigma$. Who said your choice is not correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ah okay I had it in my head that there could only be one valid choice . So basically there are infinitely many elements fixed by $\sigma$ but also infinitely many choices not fixed by alpha and we just have to be sure not to mistakenly choose the latter ? Is the fact that there are infinitely many elements fixed due to the fact that this is a cyclotomic extension ?

Comment: It depends on what the notes want to do with this fixed value. If the notes just need $w^2+w^{18}$ to be fixed, that's fine. However, while many elements are fixed, there is only one maximal subfield that is fixed, and as far as I can tell, $w+w^9\notin \Bbb Q(w^2+w^{18})$.

Comment: @Arthur the notes went on to use that choice of fixed value to figure out the fixed field of $\langle 9, 19 \rangle >$ , perhaps it easier with that choice I haven't gotten around to trying to use my own choice to do so yet . But let me see If I have this straight you're basically saying that any element within an extension which is the fixed field of some group of automorphisms will be fixed ( makes sense) but that we need to try and find an element such that the extension contains all other possible fixed values .

Comment: So in my example as $w+w^9 $is not $\Bbb Q(w^2+w^{18})$  then $ \Bbb Q(w^2+w^{18})$ can't be the maximal fixed field ( and so isn't really the fixed field ?) Is my choice the one that then creates the maximal fixed field ?

Comment: $(\omega+\omega^9)^2=\omega^2+\omega^{18}-2$.

Comment: What @Arthur said follows also from the fact that $w^2+w^{18}$ is also fixed by the automorphism $\tau:w\mapsto w^{11}$, but $\tau$ maps $w+w^9$ to its negative.  Therefore $w^2+w^{18}$ belongs to a strictly smaller field than $w+w^9$. In this sense your element is better than the other suggestion. May be whoever prepared those lecture notes wants to do something else with their choice of element? Impossible to tell without seeing them :-)

Comment: You are right that the fixed field of $\langle 9\rangle$ is generated by $\omega+\omega^9$. It contains but is not generated  by $\omega^2 +\omega^{18}$ - this latter element is also fixed by $\langle -1\rangle$, and $\langle 9, -1\rangle\not=\langle 9\rangle$.

Comment: Ahh, I missed your reply to Arthur. Yes, your element is not fixed by that other automorphism ($=\sigma\tau$ with my choice of $\tau$). That explains everything. The teacher was looking for a smaller field, and needed an element fixed by all the automorphisms in their chosen subgroup of the Galois group.